# How to register custom data provider in C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ado.net, dataprovider

We have Middle tier that provide data. We are trying to write a custom data provider. I have overriden the intefaces of SYstem.Data namespace like IDbCommand, IdbConnection and generated dlls.

We wanted to register the dll.So, that it should be listed in Data Source type window of ssrs.

We are not able to register it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Development Setup**

On your development machine, the DLL for your Data Extension needs to be installed in the Visual Studio directory. This will be something like:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

In this same folder you need to add the Data Extension to **RSReportDesigner.config** as follows:
In the `<Extensions>`  `<Data>` section, add the following line:

```
<Extension Name="MyDataExtension" Type="My.Name.Space.MyDataExtensionClass"/>
```

In the `<Extensions>`  `<Designer>` section, add the following line:

```
<Extension Name="MyDataExtension" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners.VDTQueryDesigner,Microsoft.ReportingServices.QueryDesigners"/>
```

You probably also need to add `Full Trust` for your data extension to function properly. Edit **RSPreviewPolicy.config** and add the following code security group:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup"
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="MyDataExtensionCodeGroup"
    Description="Code group for my data processing extension">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        Url="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\MyDataExtension.dll"
    />
</CodeGroup>
```

Now you can use your data processing extension in Visual Studio.

**Server Setup**

On The Reporting Services server, the Data Extension DLL needs to be installed in the SQL Server Reporting Services directory. This will be something like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin
```

In the main `ReportServer` directory above the `bin` directory you need to add the Data Extension to **RSReportServer.config**. In the `<Extensions>`  `<Data>` section, add the following line:

```
<Extension Name="MyDataExtension" Type="My.Name.Space.MyDataExtensionClass"/>
```

To give the DLL full trust, edit **RSSrvPolicy.config** and add the following code security group:

```
<CodeGroup class="UnionCodeGroup" 
    version="1"
    PermissionSetName="FullTrust"
    Name="MyDataExtensionCodeGroup"
    Description="Code group for my data processing extension">
    <IMembershipCondition class="UrlMembershipCondition"
        version="1"
        Url="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin\MyDataExtension.dll"
    />
</CodeGroup>
```

Comment: Thank you. I am able to use my Custom Data Source. But, when i try to preview the report it display following error: An attempt has been made to use Data Extension 'CUSTOM_DATASOURCE' that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition of Reporting Services.

Comment: Questions covering new issues should be asked as entirely new questions. Please create a new question for this new problem so we can cover that issue separately.