# SSRS how to render HTML escaped character

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to render a column which has lots of HTML escaped characters, such as &#0945 for alpha, &#0946 for beta. I use SSRS 2012's placeholder property to render it as HTML markup type. This feature looks like only works with HMTL tags, not escaped characters. 
Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on the non-design surface of your report and click `Report Properties...`. Click the `References` option, click `Add` in `Add or remove assemblies` and add `System.Web` from the `.NET` options.

Click the `Code` option and add the following code:

```
Function Decode(ByVal EncodedString AS String) AS String
  Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(EncodedString)
End Function
```

For your field value, use the expression:

```
=Code.Decode(Fields!MyField.Value)
```

Comment: Thanks Chris for your quick answer. I got the following error message:
[rsRuntimeErrorInExpression] The Value expression for the textrun ‘SCOPE.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.

Comment: You can probably change the trust level of the assembly to get it to work - [check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665409/how-to-register-custom-data-provider-in-c-sharp/16682068#16682068) for how to do it