# SSRS does not show &#9745; character?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Using "Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2012" to develop reports under SSRS Report Builder.
I have a data-field in the dataset that is a string value such as `&#9745;`  which represents a checkbox symbol that can be:  ☐ or ☑ or ☒ in HTML.
SSRS does NOT allow this to appear on the report as the checkbox symbol -- it shows the value `&#9745;` as literal text.

Research brought me to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765335/ssrs-how-to-render-html-escaped-character) by @Chris Latta.
I have set the textbox properties to show "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles", but still, it renders as literal text `&#9745;`.  
I have added code `Return System.Web.HttpUtility.HTMLDecode(textValue)`
 and added a reference to System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0 but now get an error: `That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.`.

I do not know how to handle that last error.

I seek a solution to have the SSRS report render the check-box symbols as noted above.

BTW -- I manually added a non-bound textbox with the following HTML-symbol-code `&#174;` and this DOES render as a registration symbol (®).

Your comments and solutions will be welcome.  Thanks...John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use all the HTML encoded symbols, but you can use special characters from various fonts. For example, for the checkbox states you can change the font to Wingdings and use the characters: ýþ¨

Comment: Thank you @stevenwhite -- great alternate set of characters.  Meets our needs.  This is our answer. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnD The Character Map :)

Comment: Thanks but exactly "where" is the Character Map?  How do I see/access this Character Map?  ..thx

Comment: @JohnD It's a utility that comes with Windows. You can search for it in the Start Menu. I don't know if there is an equivalent for macs.

Comment: Thank you very much -- excellent information.  I want to ++ your answer, but could not.  Thanks very much!!!